# Does the Android Studio emulator delay?

Tags: android, emulation, delay

Part of the app that I'm designing asks the user to tap a button ten times, then based on the rate at which they're tapping, return the average BPM (beats per minute). I've noticed that there seems to be a delay between me clicking the mouse and the emulator showing the button being clicked, but I wasn't sure if that meant anything.

The problem is that the BPM it gives me back is nowhere near accurate. If I'm correct then BPM should be equal to ((10 taps of the button)*(60 seconds in a minute))/(the number of seconds it took to tap the button 10 times), but this apparently doesn't work with my code. Oddly enough, a much more accurate multiple than 60 has been 52 consistently, and I can't figure out why.

In case it's a coding error, here's the attached method:

```
        public void buttonOnClick(View v){
    Button button=(Button) v;
    TextView counts = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    TextView bpmText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    if(total==10){
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
    }
    total=total-1;
    counts.setText(total+"");
    if(total == 0){
        long elapseTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
        double secs = elapseTime/1000000000.0;
        counts.setText("");
        button.setEnabled(false);
        button.setText("");
        bpm = (int)((10*BPM_CONSTANT)/secs);
        bpmText.setText(bpm+"");
    }
}
```

BPM_CONSTANT being the multiple, which I believe should be 60.

Is it the computer, or is it my logic? Or perhaps my clicking just isn't accurate? Feedback appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Casting the bpm calculation result to an `int` causes more loss of precision than necessary. Use `(int)Math.round(double)` instead.